# Why is my global variable "vectorControles" not updated after externalization?

Tags: java, scope

I have the following problem:
A class called "PanelPrincipal" which extends "JPanel" and implements "Externalizable".

Run the methods:

```
public PanelPrincipal() {

}
public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
    out.writeObject(vectorControles);
    ...
}
public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException,  ClassNotFoundException {
    vectorControles.clear();
    vectorControles = (Vector<Control>)in.readObject();
    ...
    System.out.println("PanelPrincipal.readExternal(ObjectInput in).vectorControles: " + vectorControles  );
}
```

Where it saves and retrieves the vector "vectorControles", which is a global variable of a "Vector" containing graphics.
It happens that when I save the project, modify the vector and reload it, the dump of the last line of "readExternal()" tells me that the modifications have been retrieved correctly, however, the modifications have no scope to "paintComponent()":

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ 
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g2 = (Graphics2D) g;        

    System.out.println("PanelPrincipal.paintComponent(Graphics g).vectorControles: " + vectorControles  );

    for(int i=0; i < vectorControles.size(); i++){
        if(vectorControles.get(i).getIdPanelContenedor() == 0) {    
            vectorControles.get(i).dibujar(g2);
        }
    } 
}
```

The terminal output and the "paintComponent()" method do not show the changes. In the middle, nothing should modify the vector.
The code is abbreviated for clarity.
I've been kicking this code around for weeks.
I would appreciate any help.
Thanks.

I need the variable "vectorControles" to be updated for the "paintComponent()" method, which is not happening.